# How to active number between 2 dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by

I have the following schema:

```
name | hire_date                   | last_date                   | active
n1   | January 20, 2018, 12:00 AM  |                             | true
n2   | October 1, 2018, 12:00 AM   | February 18, 2020, 12:00 AM | false
n3   | October 15, 2018, 12:00 AM  |                             | true
n4   | January 12 2019, 12:00 AM   |                             | true
n5   | February 12, 2019, 12:00 AM |                             | true
n6   | December 12, 2019, 12:00 AM | January 15, 2020, 12:00 AM  | false
n7   | February 17, 2020, 12:00 AM |                             | true
```

I need to extract the monthly count of the total number of `active` employees.

I am trying it with join the table with itself, and get a count of rows, but not sure how to proceed:

```
select 
-- ot1.name, ot2.name, ot1.hire_date, ot2.hire_date, ot1.last_date, ot2.last_date, 
date_trunc('month', ot1.hire_date) AS hire_dates, count(ot1.hire_date)
from ops_teammates ot1
 join ops_teammates ot2 ON ot1.hire_date >= ot2.hire_date 
 group by hire_dates
order by ot1.hire_date, ot2.hire_date;
```

How can I get the count like

```
Jan 2018, 1
Oct 2018, 3
Jan 2019, 4
Feb 2019, 5
Dec 2019, 6
Jan 2020, 5
Feb 2020, 5
```

Comment: tag your db name

Comment: how the count is 5 in feb,2020

Comment: Because one person left and one person joined

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union all` and aggregation::

```
select month_start, sum(cnt),
       sum(sum(cnt)) over (order by month_start) as running_cnt
from (
    select 1 cnt, date_trunc('month', hire_date) month_start from ops_teammates 
    union all
    select -1, date_trunc('month', last_date) + interval '1 month' from ops_teammates  where last_date is not null
)
group by month_start
order by month_start
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me count per month, whereas i want to have cumulative count over months.

Comment: @dorado: this query (should) give you the count of users that were active at the 1st day of each month, which is how I understood your question: *I need to extract the monthly count of the total number of active employees.*

Comment: You are right, but what I need is the cumulative count, means summing this months data with data for all the previous months.

Comment: @dorado: the last update by Gordon Linoff should do what you want.